# how to detect clouds in image using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

i am working on a project using opencv in python in which i want to detect the clouds in an image. i have tried a lot of things but i am stuck.i couldn't find the exact range of cloud color values for hsv color space. this is the code i have tried. the following code detect some of the clouds but not all.this is the code.i have also attached an image which i am getting from this code.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('E:/sky.jpg', 1)
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

white = np.array([255, 255, 255])
lowerBound = np.array([30,30,30])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lowerBound, white)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
cv2.imwrite("E:/clouds.jpg",res)

cv2.imshow("mywindow",res)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You assign a value of [255,255,255] for white in HSV colorspace? HSV is not RGB

Comment: if i change [255,255,255] to [0,0,100] which is hsv for [255,255,255] then it make it all black. the image become all black..is there any problem with my code?

Comment: "If I change..." are you blindly trying combinations of numbers? Where does the [30,30,30] come from? What color does it represent in HSV (remember you are not in RGB)

Comment: [30,30,30] is a dark greenish color in HSV, nothing to do with your sky or clouds color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking white color using python opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588146/tracking-white-color-using-python-opencv)

Comment: then why did it give me that black area which is cloud?

Comment: what should i do? kindly help me with my code to detect the clouds in that attached image

Comment: @Tehseen Can you share the original image containing clouds?

Answer (score 0):

Try not changing the image to HSV color space.
Remove line

```
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

The rest of the code clearly shows you are working with a RGB color based scheme and you have no idea what HSV is. Frankly speaking, i don't see the need for you to work with HSV color space in the first place. It can be done even with grayscale image representation.

Comment: now i understand that i was working with RGB but now i don't know the color range for clouds. i have searched a lot but couldn't find the hsv values to detect clouds.

Comment: and by removing the line of code which convert the image from BGR to HSV  is not giving me my desired result

Comment: then you should go and do some research on the function name adaptivethreshold